# Valid Signing Identity Not Found status

Tags: xcode, certificate

In my Xcode > Organizer > Devices

I have created a distribution Provisioning Profile created today by selecting the distribution certificate from the provisioning portal and the App ID.

But the status of the provisioning profile inside the Organizer shows "Valid Signing Identity not found"

I have doubled check in my MacBook Keychain Access, it has the certificate that is exactly from the Provisioning Portal's Certificates > Distribution.

I have downloaded the cert from provisioning profile, double clicked on the .cer file and it just open the Keychain Access.

Yet, I still have the same issue.

What should I do?

Answer (score 4):

1. all your xcode certificates in keychain needs to be set to (**Use System Defaults)** not, approved always **OR** never approved. you can see them by double clicking them.
2. Xcode > Organizer > Devices > **Teams**: "Identity valid for signing", needs to be imported, and have green marks on it/them.
3. Xcode > Targets > "your project" > build setting > **code signing** > set them to "Automatic Profile Selector" then Iphone developer or distribution, in your case Distribution.

clean & build

if it doesn't work try changing "**Code signing**", Also certificates should be showed in the code signing.

This was my biggest problem off all time, it was annoying.. Hope It helps!

let me know if theres still a problem!